# Adding a summary to a document

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

not sure the best way to go about this but I am interested in adding a document summary, so when that document appears in the searchresults page , I can access the summary by hovering over the file, or a dropdown from a column using metadata etc.

Currently a few lines of text from the document is shown, but often it's not very helpful to show at a glance whether the document is of interest. I'm guessing that can be made longer somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have done this as a metadata column associated with the document. We tried including it in the document (there are properties for this in the Word property panel for example) but the users fail to complete the summary. It was easier to add it as required metadata.

As for finding and displaying it, there is a `Description` managed property that you can use to display the content of the field in Search Results but you'll have to map the crawled property yourself or create a new Managed Property for your purposes. This would require editing the Display Template to achieve your desired result. Not hard to do, but tedious if you are new to SharePoint and, with the new Modern search UI, you won't see the results of your efforts outside of the SharePoint Search Center.

Comment: I totally agree with Matt.  This is not trivial.  You'll need to add a summary field to your document library.  After it is crawled, map it to a managed property, and then surface this in the display templates where you wish to see this.  This is advanced stuff.